# Avoid duplicates with multipal column in INSERT INTO SELECT query in darby sql NOT Exists not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with 4 column like

```
Table h1
----------
ID   Name school home 
1    A    x      11
2    B    y      12
3    C    z      13

Table h2
----------
ID   Name school home 
1    A    x      14
2    B    s      15
3    D    z      16
```

i want to insert table h2 data in table h1 without duplicate with checking some column i want to insert row id 2 and 3 only

i am try

Using NOT EXISTS: not work , Using NOT IN: i can only use 1 column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would `NOT EXISTS` not work ? here you can go :

```
INSERT INTO table_h1 (ID, Name, school, home)
    SELECT h2.ID, h2.Name, h2.school, h2.home 
    FROM table_h2 h2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_h1 h1 WHERE h1.id = h2.id AND h1.Name = h2.Name AND h1.school = h2.school);
```

Comment: Thanks Working Fine